# How to autohide the messagebox in C#

Tags: c#, wpf

example

```
ScriptManager.RegisterClientScriptBlock
(this.Page, this.GetType(), "MyScript", "alert('Saved Successfully !!');", true);
```

but scriptmanager is show as error

Comment: Show your code and your error.

Comment: I think I know this joke hold on....

Comment: did you use `ScriptManager` tag

Comment: ScriptManager.RegisterClientScriptBlock(this.Page, this.GetType(), "MyScript", "alert('Saved Successfully !!');", true);

Comment: that a code... bt it show error in scriptmannager - doesnot exit current conntent

Comment: simple c# code for ALERT msg like saved succesfully

Comment: do you have embeded ajax correct version

Answer (score 0):

in WPF you can show message box like this

```
MessageBoxResult result = MessageBox.Show("saved successfully");
```

and if you want to close it after sometime then use this

```
AutoClosingMessageBox.Show("Text", "Caption", 1000);
```

and the class definition goes like this

```
public class AutoClosingMessageBox {
    System.Threading.Timer _timeoutTimer;
    string _caption;
    AutoClosingMessageBox(string text, string caption, int timeout) {
        _caption = caption;
        _timeoutTimer = new System.Threading.Timer(OnTimerElapsed,
            null, timeout, System.Threading.Timeout.Infinite);
        MessageBox.Show(text, caption);
    }
    public static void Show(string text, string caption, int timeout) {
        new AutoClosingMessageBox(text, caption, timeout);
    }
    void OnTimerElapsed(object state) {
        IntPtr mbWnd = FindWindow(null, _caption);
        if(mbWnd != IntPtr.Zero)
            SendMessage(mbWnd, WM_CLOSE, IntPtr.Zero, IntPtr.Zero);
        _timeoutTimer.Dispose();
    }
    const int WM_CLOSE = 0x0010;
    [System.Runtime.InteropServices.DllImport("user32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
    static extern IntPtr FindWindow(string lpClassName, string lpWindowName);
    [System.Runtime.InteropServices.DllImport("user32.dll", CharSet = System.Runtime.InteropServices.CharSet.Auto)]
    static extern IntPtr SendMessage(IntPtr hWnd, UInt32 Msg, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam);
}
```

Refference : thanx to @DmitryG